# How to remove quotes and the brackets within a tuple in python to format the data

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to print only the maximum occurring character and its count.

```
import collections

s = raw_input()
k = (collections.Counter(s).most_common(1)[0])
```

for lists, we have strip `"".join` method but how to deal with tuple the opposite way, i.e., removing the quotes and bracket.

So, here is what I want the output to be without quotes and brackets

```
input = "aaabucted"

output = ('a', 3)
```

I want the  output to be `a, 3`.

Comment: You can pass a `list` or `tuple` (or some other things) to `join()`.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33304115/edit) to your question to show the output of your actual code and the expected result.

Comment: So you want to print `'a', 3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotes aren't in the data, they are just added when displaying the content on the screen. If you print the value rather than the string representation of the tuple you'll see there are no quotes or brackets in the data. So, the problem isn't "how do I remove the quotes and brackets?" but rather "how do I format the data the way I want?".

For example, using your code you can see the character and the count without the quotes and brackets like this:

```
print k[0], k[1]  # python 2
print(k[0], k[1]) # python 3
```

And, of course, you can use string formatting:

```
print "%s, %i" % k   # python 2
print("%s, %i" % k)  # python 3
```

Comment: I like `print "%s, %i" % k`!

Comment: e.g. print(' '.join("%s, %i" % v + '\n' for v in k.most_common(10)))

Answer (score 7):

You can make a list and join it, first converting all to strings:

```
",".join([str(s) for s in list(k)])
```